# OneDrive uses a lot of space. How can I clean this?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, onedrive

I've got a problem. OneDrive is really large (~2 GB) and I don't know how to remove/clean it (without wiping the whole device).

**Is there any option I can clean this up?**

Notes:

- Already cleaned temporary files
- Disconnected OneDrive from the account -> this is just the app

[image: OneDrive space usage]

Comment: Do you have a large number of photos/videos waiting to be uploaded? You could try resetting the app, either from the same Settings page where you took that screenshot (tap on OneDrive -> Advanced options -> Reset) or from within the app itself (Settings -> About OneDrive -> Reset app).

Comment: Did you tried reinstalling OneDrive?

Comment: @indrek I only have a reset option within the app, not the advanced option. Unfortunately this doesn't worked and seems to be broken. The app goes off and on within a second and nothing seems to have changed. The user is still logged in, despite the description saying the user will be logged out. Nevertheless: Please add this advice as answer, as a may help others and is really not obvious.

Comment: @User5 Not possible. This is a "core" app. I can't remove it. Would have tried this. I think, finally I well need to reset the whole phone to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Same problem here, and the "Reset" button of the OneDrive app is grayed out on my phone.

Comment: Plus, after emptying OneDrive's trash bin and deleting a few files from the shared folder, the used space *increased* by 3 MB.

Answer (score 3):

As nothing worked, I've reset the phone.

Comment: I had the same symptoms but with outlook. Did the same.

Answer (score -1):

Without wiping the whole device, you can use an external memory device to enhance your device space as there is no any other way to clean the space that the OneDrive uses.